# Tutorial: Controlling a Mobile Robot with its Range Sensor

Tags: gazebo-sensor, gazebo-tutorial

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I tried to implement the tutorial plugin `my_plugin_with_sensor.cc` (explained [here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/control_robot/mobile_base_laser)) in the Pioneer robot I am using in my world model. The simulation is not working as expected and mentioned in the tutorial page. The moment I start Gazebo, my robot starts moving back if gain <= 2.0 else starts tumbling and goes crazy and goes out of the solid boundary walls.

What shall I do ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2198/tutorial:-controlling-a-mobile-robot-with-its-range-sensor/) by [amit](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/166/amit/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [suvrat](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/438/suvrat/) on 2013-07-25**:
can u plz tell me how u solve the problem as i m aslo facing same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

i have solved this problem by little modification in my code
if (min_dist < this->laser->GetRangeMax())
{

```
    **double torque = this->gain *( (min_dist - target_dist)*0.1 );**
printf("torque %lf\n",torque);

    this->leftWheelJoint->SetForce(0, torque);
    this->rightWheelJoint->SetForce(0, torque);
  }
```

now it is not starts tumbling and goes crazy and goes out of the solid boundary walls.

---

Originally posted by [suvrat](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/438/suvrat/) with karma: 53 on 2013-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0